# Why does ReactRouter's Route path ":params" read as "styles.css" in express?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, react-router

I am using Reactrouter in my front end and Express in my back end. 
When I am routing with custom parameters which im using for a findbyID fetch for a component, I found
through my error log on express side read the custom param as styles.css.

**React Rounter Side:**

```
<Route path="/id/:id" component={Something} />
```

**On Express:**

```
app.get("/id/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  database.findById(id, (e, found) => {
    console.log(id);
    if (!e) {
      console.log(found);
    } else {
      console.log(e);
      console.log("consult stack overflow");
    }
  });
});
```

**Error Message:**

`MongooseError [CastError]: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "styles.css" at path "_id" for model "database"`

Why does it do this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out I have a Link to a styles.css in my index html page. soon as i removed that everything worked the way it should have. So if anyone Is stuggling with this exact same issue later down the line here's hoping this helps you. Check your index.html file for any matching names.